# How to dynamically count totals of records with a certain value?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm looking to create a count of my 'trolleys' field which is dynamic. This should count the number of trolleys on any given day by the type (e.g. a,b,c). However, I don't want to create a static column which only counts by the type (A,B,C). However, instead I would require a dynamic count which would count depending on the 'type' as we currently don't know which types will be used as this would change on a day to day basis.

**Sample data:**
[image: Sample data for count]

I'm looking to create this in Ireport 5.6.

**Proposed Outcome**

[image: Count By Type]

Any ideas would be excellent :)

Comment: You can use [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups). The JR has variable (*$V{groupName_COUNT}*) with number of records in group

Comment: In your case you can add the group for *"Type"* column (for example with *typeGroup* name) and use the *$V{typeGroup_COUNT}* variable. Don't forget to add sorting by *Type*

Comment: Another way is to have the number of records in group in field. If you are using *jdbc* based datasource you can calculate such number with help of sql

Comment: Hello @AlexK I have read the link you have provided in your first comment. I do not know how I create the group in the GUI interface of ireport. and for further info, we use ireport to create the xml file that gets imported into our own application which populates the data into the report.

Comment: In your case (dynamic grouping) it is better to use Java API (DynamicReports or DynamicJasper or JasperReports API)

Comment: What about the using of Java code?

Comment: @AlexK Thank your for point out groups, it has achieved in counting the trolleys per type, I added the group by right clicking the top level of the report on the report inspector and adding report group. Using the wizard I selected the field type and changed my count variable reset type to the new group.

Only thing left to do now is format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashMap to count your fields, like this.

```
public Map<String, List<Class>> sortByKey(List<Class> values){
   Map<String, List<Class>> map = new HashMap<>();

   for(Class value : values){
      if(map.containsKey(value.type)){
           List<Class> valueByKey = map.get(value.type);
           valueByKey.add(value);
      }
      else{
           List<Class> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
           newValues.add(value);
           map.put(value.type, newValues);
      }
   }      

   return map;
}
```

Code above sort your data by key, which is in your example "type" field. You can then get number of each type by checking the size of the list by the specific key. Example bellow.

```
List<Class> tmp = map.get("a");
int count = tmp.size();
```